# How to still use hostPath with the Baseline Pod Security level?

Tags: kubernetes, podsecuritypolicy

I need to migrate from Pod Security Policy to Pod Security Admission. The Baseline Pod Security Level is what I need to use, but it does not support hostPath. How Do I use the Baseline pod security level and still use hostPath?

[Migrate From PSP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/migrate-from-psp/#eliminate-mutating-fields)

Comment: You almost never use `hostPath:`.  If you're thinking about security things at all, it's a way for Pods to compromise the Node; even if not, since a `hostPath:` directory isn't tied to a specific Node, it's a way to misplace data if a Pod gets deleted and rescheduled on a different Node.  Use a different storage mechanism.

Comment: @DavidMaze If I did end up using hostPath, can I get around the Baseline Pod Security level by using a pod security admission policy?